# ScaleDrawable has its own constant state?

Tags: android, performance, android-resources

I've seen the [blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html) about how android handles drawables and how to save memory using mutations, creating different constant states.

Lets say I have a bitmap pic1.jpg which I use it in some part of my app and I have a ScaleDrawable that scales down the resource pic1.jpg.

Q1: Will they share the same constant state?

Q2: Will android load 2 images in memory (pic1 and the scaled version of it) or just pic1 ?

Q3: Is this better, regarding loading performance and memory consumption, than having 2 resources with different sizes?

**Update:** 
ScaleDrawable doesn't seem to be working, at least I've tried it out and the drawable is not shown.

Comment: Cyril Mottier has a great talk that explains how drawables work internally - https://speakerdeck.com/cyrilmottier/mastering-android-drawables

Comment: Good talk but it doesn't answer really answer my question. What's not clear for me (and haven't found a clear explanation of it) if using a ScaleDrawable is better (in means of performance) than having 2 images of different sizes (one for each device resolution).